# Problem with webfonts in firefox and links in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, firefox, google-webfonts

Hi people I'm currently making a website for a school project but I'm having the following problems.

1.
Webfonts looking terrible in Firefox on Windows 7.

2.
IE showing a thick white border around last 2 links in left menu.

Maybe someone have experienced something similar and found a workaround or simply know how to fix this.

Best regards,
Alexander Freiling

Comment: Please try to restrain your questions to one question. ;) Also, it wouldn't hurt if you clarified what "looking terrible" means exactly. And the second question is absolutely pointless without a code example.

Answer (score 0):

So far `-webkit-font-smooth` is the only thing I've seen that helps with webfonts. Unfortunately, it only seems to work in Safari and Chrome at the moment. There is a `font-smooth` property in CSS3, but none of the browsers have implemented it yet.

Comment: Unlikely to be implemented in any other browsers given that `font-smooth` has been dropped from CSS3 long ago (is only present in a working draft from 2002). See discussion under https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=640134. Not that it is clear that this is what the user is asking about here...